# When is tensor product zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The following theorem is given in Exercise 3 of Chapter 2 of "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by M.F. Atiyah and I.G. MacDonald:

Theorem
Let $A$ be a local ring, and let $M$ and $N$ be finitely generated $A$-modules.

If $M\otimes N=0$, then either $M=0$ or $N=0$.

I'm interested in whether the conclusion of this theorem holds when the assumptions are weakened.

Specifically, I consider the following cases:

1.$A$ is not a local ring.

2.$A$ is a local ring, but at least one of $M$ and $N$ is not finitely generated.

For case 1, there exist counterexamples, and the following are such examples:

$\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=0$ for $m$,$n$ where $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

$\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}Q$ for $m$ where $m>1$.

Here, I have two question.

1.For case 2, do counterexamples exist?

2.Do counterexamples exist where neither $M$ nor $N$ is  finitely generated in both cases 1 and 2?

Comment: There are local rings where the maximal ideal $m \ne 0$ equals its square (this can only happen if $m$ is not finitely generated), i.e. $m = m^2$, which means $m \otimes R/m = 0$. Then $m \otimes (\oplus_{i=1}^\infty R/m) = 0$ also